# How can I change description Google shows in the search results for a 301 redirect URL?

Tags: seo, google, 301-redirect, search-results

We transferred our domain from our old CMS to our new one but we still have the same domain. Let's say our domain is now `example.com`.

I Googled ***our domain* protein powder** and a page from our old site shows up.  Now when you get to `example.com/protein-powder` on our new site it was a 404. We made it a 301 redirect: `example.com/protein-powder` to `example.com/protein-pack`.

Now when doing that same search on Google, `example.com/protein-powder` still shows up, but Google is using the meta description and title from the old site. How can I change the description and title Google is using when it's already a 301 redirect?

Comment: Request google to index the new page or delete the old url from console

Comment: I'am little confused. "example.com/protein-powder still shows up, but Google is using the meta description and title from the old site" -  But example.com/protein-powder is the old url right?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really change Title and Description in Google results.

When did you place the 301 redirection? Google should update quickly if you send it your new sitemap including `example.com/protein-pack` via the Search Console

Answer (score 1):

In Search Console, enter the new url in the search bar. [image]
After that you can do "Test Live Url"  and if everything is fine, you can request indexing of the new URL. This will speed up the process of Google discovering what has happened.